# How can I retrieve all Room list for Exchange Server 2007

Tags: c#, asp.net, exchange-server, exchangewebservices, exchange-server-2007

I am trying to find all Meeting rooms for Exchange Server 2007 using c#. 
I found an easy way to do this by using EWS Managed API:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exchange/hh532566(v=exchg.80).aspx

Unfortunately, GetRoomLists() does not work for Exchange Server 2007. 
I am hoping if some has worked or know how can I find meeting rooms on exchange server 2007, that would be a great help. 
I want to see all the meeting room available on Exchange server and then want to use their properties.

Is there a way I can show all the existing room and then use its properties like Phone/Notes tab information?

Any help or suggestion would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance !!

Answer (score 0):

From my experience working with Exchange 2003 and 2007 this was not possible, based on how data is stored and structured. Resource (Room) is just another contact/user/mailbox, until you create an event, than you can designate that contact as Room (via [AttendeeType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exchange/exchangewebservices.attendeetype.attendeetype%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx)).

In EWS 2007 you can use [ResolveName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exchange/aa493895%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx) method to find contacts/rooms.